# NetBeans: How to define the syntax highlight and validation for the new file extension? (on .sass example)

Tags: netbeans, sass

Currently `.sass` extension is not supported in NetBeans IDE (the `SASS file` from the `Create new File` menu is actually `.sccs` extension file). To add the `.sass` support, besides new file type definition it's also required to define the syntax highlight and syntax validation.

Although I don't have any experience in NetBeans development, I can use the `.jade` file definitions as example: like `.sass`, in `jade` the nesting declares by indentation. Where I can find the `.jade` syntax highlight and validation definition and what else should I do to begin the `.sass` support development?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe those tutorials can help you to integrate a new language into NetBeans: http://wiki.netbeans.org/SyntaxColoringANTLR and http://wiki.netbeans.org/New_Language_Support_Tutorial_Antlr

There already should be a grammar file for sass, but only guessing. Or you can try to implement it as NBS. It has limited functionality but it works for syntax highlighting and braces matching and some other features. See it here what it is: https://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/schliemann/. The tutorial is kind of outdated, so maybe not everything will work anymore, but it will give you an entry point. You can clone this repo and change the stuff for your needs, I tested it and it works nicely: https://github.com/cgunnels/Netbeans-Cucumber-Feature

I'm also working on a plugin, where I can collect all nbs files and add those languages to NetBeans more easily then the normal process is, to implement a full featured language to it.

If you have any questions or needs or whatever, join our slack chan too: https://netbeans.signup.team/

Lots of people who can help.